# Propagating uncertainties using random forest out-of-bag accuracy estimates

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, uncertainty, error-propagation

Let's say I train a random forest on some data and get an out-of-bag accuracy estimate of 90%. I then predict a quantity using this trained forest. What should be the uncertainty I give to that quantity?

Comment: do you assume that the new observation comes from the same population as the ones you used for training?

Comment: @Antoine yes I do